# How to run spring boot repackage goal

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I want to run only repackage goal that comes from `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin.

I tried

`mvn spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage`

but I got:

`Plugin not found in any plugin repository`

## update

I also tried

`mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage`

I got:
`Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source file must be provided`

and this is the full error log:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage
> (default-cli) on project MyServer: Execution default-cli of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage
> failed: Source file must be provided -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage
> (default-cli) on project MyServer: Execution default-cli of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:repackage
> failed: Source file must be provided

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've encountered [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22317), although the [developers seem to indicate that this goal should not be run standalone at all](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22317#issuecomment-657650216).